# How to add borders for code in ACE Editor, which will update dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ace-editor

I want to add borders/outlines for a block of code in ace editor. The block border should update/grow as and when I insert new code inside the block. Which means, when a new line is created, the border should wrap that line also.
Is this possible in ace editor?

Please refer the below image to have a better understanding of what I actually need.

[image]